# how to spsc_queue.pop() this struct?

Tags: c++, boost, struct, queue, lock-free

I'm trying to `spsc_queue.pop()` this `struct`

```
enum action_type {
    SUBSCRIBE,
    UNSUBSCRIBE,
    MESSAGE
};

struct action {
    action() = default ;
    action(action_type t, connection_hdl h) : type(t), hdl(h) {}
    action(action_type t, server::message_ptr m) : type(t), msg(m) {}

    action_type type;
    websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl;
    server::message_ptr msg;
};
```

with

```
action a;
while(m_actions.pop(a)){
    ...
```

but whenever I test with

```
std::cout << "'" << a.type << "'" << std::endl;
```

`'0'` is written to the terminal, but it should only be one of the values of `action_type`.  I have read that the default value for a `struct` is `0`, but why can't `spsc_queue.pop()` set `a`?

([`boost::lockfree::spsc_queue`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `SUBSCRIBE` *is* `0`. If you want to give `SUBSCRIBE` a different value you can initialize the enumerator, e.g., with `1`:

```
enum action_type {
    SUBSCRIBE = 1,
    UNSUBSCRIBE,
    MESSAGE
};
```

The other enumerators will get the respective next integer value.